# ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException : 6

Tags: arrays, exception, bounds, out, slot

```
public boolean horizontal(Populate a, int[][][] ar, int row, int col, int dep)
    {
        ar = new int[6][6][6];
        a.pop(ar);
        for(dep=0;dep<6;dep++)
        {
            for(col=0;col<6;col++)
            {
                for(int count=0;count<5;count++)
                {    
                    int num = ar[row][col][dep];
                    int num1 = ar[row+1][col][dep];
                    if(num==num1)
                    {
                        count1++;
                    }
                    row++;

                }   

            }

        }
        if(count1==5)
            return true;
        else
            return false;
    }
```

This code is supposed to scan a 3d array for a horizontal row of 6 (like a slot machine) and returns true if it does and false otherwise. It compiles but gets an ArrayOutOfBoundsException:6 when I try to run it.

```
for(int count=0;count<5;count++)
```

Even if I try to change this line above to something like this below (as in just lowering how far the loop goes), it still goes out of bounds.

```
 for(int count=0;count<2;count++)
```

Any suggestions or solutions are appreciated. Thank you.

This is where I call the method if that helps at all.

```
    public class runCheck
    {
        public static void main(String[] args)
        {
            Populate ch = new Populate();
            int[][][] ar = new int[6][6][6];
            ch.pop(ar);
            ArrayList al = new ArrayList();
            scan a = new scan();
            boolean abool = a.horizontal(ch,ar,0,0,0);
            if(abool==true)
                al.add(true);
        }
    }
```

Comment: When showing ArrayIndexOutOfBounds, this means your indices on your array go over the size of your initialization.

Comment: Echo each indices when you need to assign or access the array and check where will it come across the exception

Comment: @BlackMaggie Maggie I'm sorry, but what do you mean by **echoing** each index?

Comment: Oh I forgot to check which language you are using.... For Java, system.out.println the indices before each line you are accessing the array

Answer (score 0):

As I'm not aware of your complete code on how you are calling this method, I'm assuming the problem is in one of these lines

int num = ar[row][col][dep];
int num1 = ar[row+1][col][dep];

row++;

The variable row may be going more than 5 throwing an array out of bounds exception.